# WP8 Animation cannot resolve TargetName

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I got a weired Problem with an animation. I have a UserControl that displays a caption and an arrow image that should turn 90° on tap. But i get an InvalidOperationException "Cannot resolve xx TargetName."

```
   <Image
        x:Name="ImageArrow"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Margin="0,0,20,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Source="/Images/konto_pfeil.png"
        Height="24"
        Width="15"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:AnimateOnDataBehavior Value="{Binding Dropped, ElementName=BaseView}">
                <local:AnimateOnDataBehavior.StoryboardTrue>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ImageArrow"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElemet.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                            To="90"
                            Duration="0:0:0.3">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </local:AnimateOnDataBehavior.StoryboardTrue>
                <local:AnimateOnDataBehavior.StoryboardFalse>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ImageArrow"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElemet.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                            To="0"
                            Duration="0:0:0.3">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </local:AnimateOnDataBehavior.StoryboardFalse>
            </local:AnimateOnDataBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
```

I am using AnimateOnDataBehavior in the same project with success so i think is not the Problem but anyway you could give it a quick look:

```
public class AnimateOnDataBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Invert the value conversion logic
    /// </summary>
    public bool Invert
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(InvertProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InvertProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Invert.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InvertProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Invert", typeof(bool), typeof(AnimateOnDataBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false));


    /// <summary>
    /// Value, object != null, string !string.IsNullOrEmpty(), bool == true, conversion logic. 
    /// </summary>
    public object Value
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(AnimateOnDataBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(ValueChanged)));
    private static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as AnimateOnDataBehavior).OnValueChanged();
    }

    public Storyboard StoryboardTrue
    {
        get { return (Storyboard)GetValue(StoryboardTrueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StoryboardTrueProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StoryboardTrue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StoryboardTrueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StoryboardTrue", typeof(Storyboard), typeof(AnimateOnDataBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public Storyboard StoryboardFalse
    {
        get { return (Storyboard)GetValue(StoryboardFalseProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StoryboardFalseProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StoryboardFalse.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StoryboardFalseProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StoryboardFalse", typeof(Storyboard), typeof(AnimateOnDataBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += (_, __) =>
        {
            Animate();
        };
    }

    private bool ConversionLogic()
    {
        object v = Value;
        bool b = false;

        if (v is string)
        {
            b = string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)v);
        }
        else if (v is bool)
        {
            b = (bool)v;
        }
        else
        {
            b = v != null;
        }

        return Invert ? !b : b;
    }

    private bool? lastFade = null;
    private void Animate()
    {
        bool bFadeIn = ConversionLogic();

        // Just stop senseless animations
        if (lastFade != null && lastFade == bFadeIn)
            return;
        lastFade = bFadeIn;

        Storyboard storyboard = bFadeIn ? StoryboardTrue : StoryboardFalse;

        if (storyboard != null)
        {
            try { storyboard.Begin(); }
            catch { }
        }
    }

    private void OnValueChanged()
    {
        Animate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try UIElement.RenderTransform instead of FrameworkElement.RenderTransform :P

Comment: Can you try defining the Storyboard in the resources of your Page and referencing using StaticResource. You essentially need to set the Target object of your Storyboard and it needs to be something containing the ImageArrow